# Check if expiration date is invalid - get current month and year without '/'

Tags: c#, date, compare

I have a user control (ascx) and in the .ascx side there are two dropdowns - one for month and one for year. These are for the expiration dates of a credit card. I would like to do some sort of comparison to compare the expiration date with the current date (to make sure the card isn't invalid). I know how to compare things, I'm just wondering how to get the current month and year without the slashes, and without the day :-)

Comment: Have you looked at the DateTime struct at all?

Answer (score 2):

you could make something like this:

```
 int mon =DateTime.Now.Month();
 int yr=DateTime.Now.Year();
 string date = mon + "-" + yr;
```

and put what you want in the middle.

Comment: I'd call `DateTime.Now` only once. Else you get a (very very unlikely) racecondition. And for good design I'd separate the logic from the call to `DateTime.Now` by passing in the current time as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I've used for checking if a credit card's expiry month and year are in the future. I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this, but it works:

```
public static bool IsValid(int month, int year)
    {
        var DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
        var MonthNow = DateTimeNow.Month;
        var YearNow = DateTimeNow.Year;

        if (year >= YearNow)
        {
            if (year > YearNow)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (year == YearNow)
            {
                if (month >= MonthNow)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }       
        }            

        return false;
    }
```

Basically, it checks if the year is either the current year or in the future, if it is then we check if it's in the future. if so then it returns true. If the year is the same as the current year, then we then check that the month is greater than or equal to the current month. If it is, we return true. If none of the conditions are met, then we return false.

Use it like this:

```
 int cardMonth = 5;
 int cardYear = 2020;
 bool cardDateIsValid = IsValid(cardMonth, cardYear);
```

As I say, I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Has not expired?

```
public static bool IsValid(int month, int year)
{
    if (year > DateTime.Today.Year) // later than current year
        return true;

    if (year < DateTime.Today.Year) // earlier than current year
        return false;

    return month >= DateTime.Today.Month; // current year
}
```

Has expired? *(inverse)*

```
public static bool IsExpired(int month, int year)
{
    if (year > DateTime.Today.Year) // later than current year
        return false;

    if (year < DateTime.Today.Year) // earlier than current year
        return true;

    return month < DateTime.Today.Month; // current year
}
```